# Writing function that determines value closest to a specific number

Tags: r

I am currently trying to achieve the following. I have also already asked ChatGPT, but unfortunately it could not help me either.

I have this code:

```
val = 14
name = c("Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Carl", "Carl", "Carl", "Carl" , "Carl" , "Carl")
month = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
product = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c")
sales = c(10, 11, 14, 10, 15, 18, 11, 22, 33, 7, 14, 15)
df = data.frame(name, month, product, sales)
```

I am looking for the code that does the following.
It should search the values of the column 'sales' for every possible combination of the variables 'name' and 'month' and stop before the last value of the respective combination that is still below the value of 'val'. When this value or row has been identified, then a new data.frame should be created, which should have three columns consisting of 'name', 'month' and the value of 'product' of the respective column.

In this case there are 6 possible combinations, so the resulting matrix has 6 rows and three columns.

As an example, val = 14. 14 is reached for the combination 'Tim' and '1' for 'product=c'. For 'Tim' and '2', for example, already at the second position and therefore 'product=b'.

Thanks a lot

Asked ChatGPT and searched online

Comment: If I copy/paste the code you provided, I get an error that "arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 12". Do you want the output in another data.frame? If so, it's helpful to give the desired output in that format so we can easily test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Hi @mikeman123 - The code you shared to create your data frame will produce an error. You have ten `names` and `months`, but twelve `products` and `sales`. It seems like you might want the row with the greatest sales value equal to or below the threshold, but I'm having trouble following the logic from the description as the sales for Tim in month 2, product 'b' is 15. Can you please update this question with an example of the output data frame?

Comment: Can you post a representation of what you expect the output to look like? It is very hard to understand what rows you would want to pull out with "stop before the last value of the respective combination that is still below the value of 'val'." You mention that for val=14, you would return "Tim" and 1, which are the values that line up with sales=14, but then you talk about "Tim" and 2 giving you product=b, which is the line *before* the highest sales value for "Tim"/2.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
val = 14
name = c("Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Carl", "Carl", "Carl", "Carl" , "Carl" , "Carl")
month = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
product = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c")
sales = c(10, 11, 14, 10, 15, 18, 11, 22, 33, 7, 14, 15)
df = data.frame(val, name, month, product, sales) # add your threshold value to your dataframe


df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(salesThreshold = sales >= val) %>% #evaluate sales vs threshold
  filter(salesThreshold == TRUE) %>% # filter to values at or above threshold
  group_by(name, month, product) %>% 
  summarise()
```

[image: sample]

The results is a 7 X 3 data frame. I read that you are looking for a result that is 6 X 3, but perhaps you did not update your expected results after updating your example code?